# Does cout treat bool as integer or integer as bool?

Tags: c++, cout

Why does this program

```
int a = 8; 
cout << a && true ;
cout << typeid(a && true).name();
```

output

> 8bool

Frankly, I expected "truebool" or "8int".

Is operator << of cout object involved in this or is it a precedence issue?

Does it convert true to 1 as in the case when we `cout << true;`?
`typeid(a && true)` gives us bool, though the `cout << a && true;` is obviously a number?

Comment: Precedence rules say: `(cout << a) && true`

Comment: Part of what you're looking for is [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha)

Comment: [Handy reading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). You'll find `<<` up in precedence 7 and `&&` way down in 14.

Comment: `cout << a && true` is equivalent, by rules of operator precedence, to `(cout << a) && true`, not to `cout << (a && true)`.

Comment: ok, I partly got it. 
this  part (cout << a) returns type:
class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >
and then basic_ostream  is conjuncted with the value true ?
I mean, why  cout && true  would ever ouput anything there is no << operator here ? it's just boolean? 
why we haven't write it like
cout << (cout << a) && true;
but it's still work   
(cout << a) will output and returned just cout
and then cout << cout && true  will  be transformed to cout << true ?
Where I am wrong? I feel like there is a complicated overloading things come up here?

Comment: `cout && true` does _not_ output anything.  The operator `&&` will invoke the boolean operator overload on the stream to return whether it is in an error state or not.  Furthermore, the operator `<<` will return a reference to the stream.  So `cout << a && true;` is like doing `cout << a; cout && true`.  As for `cout << (cout << a) && true` that's just bogus.  But for the sake of argument, that would equate to `cout << a; cout << cout; cout && true;`

Comment: Okay, I see, so it's clear now. thanks everyone!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operators don't output correct results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860748/logical-operators-dont-output-correct-results)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed it is an [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) issue.  `<<` has a higher precedence than `&&`.

One shorthand trick you can use to interpret an integer value to bool is to double-NOT it:

```
cout << !!a;
```

This is a matter of style, which may be divisive within the C++ community.  So, if you don't want to be controversial, then the following may be more acceptable:

```
cout << (a ? true : false);
cout << static_cast<bool>(a);
cout << (a != 0);
```

Personally, I think that `(a && true)` is somewhat ugly.  But I'm sure there are some who would argue otherwise.

In the end, the compiler should be generating the same result no matter how you write it.