# Logical operators don't output correct results

Tags: c++, logical-operators

Here is the code that I'm struggling with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a{ 6 }, b{ 9 };
    cout << !(a < 5) && !(b >= 7);
}
```

Every time I run this code it outputs 1. Why doesn't it output 0?

Comment: Have you checked operator precedence?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Also don't ever `using namespace std`, even (especially?) in a simple example. Just don't.

Comment: Try `std::cout << (!(a < 5) && !(b >= 7));` (note the extra parentheses).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've been tripped up by the semantic overloading we give the `<<` operator in C++.

This operator comes from C, where it is used exclusively for bit-shifting integers.

Because of that, it has a lower [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `&&` operator.  C++'s use of the `<<` operator for stream insertion doesn't change that.   The `<<` will be evaluated before the `&&`.

Thus

```
cout << !(a < 5) && !(b >= 7);
```

first inserts `!(a<5)` (true, since `a==6`) into the stream, printing a `1`. Then it evaluates the return value of that (a reference to `cout`), converts it to boolean, then evaluates the `&&` (essentally `(!cout.fail() && !(b>=7))`), discarding the result.

You need more parentheses:

```
cout << (!(a < 5) && !(b >= 7));
```

However,

```
cout << (a>=5 && b < 7);
```

would be clearer.