# Why is my output 1 for this logical operation

Tags: c++

im current learning c++ and am trying to understand logical operators. however, this program i wrote seem to output 1 even though the output is suppose to be 0. any helps with this? thankyou

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A, B, C;
    A = 2;
    B = 1;
    C = 3;
    cout << "A >= B: " << (A >= B);  \\ output: 1
    cout << "\nA == C: " << (A == C);  \\ output: 0
    cout << endl << (A >= B) && (A==C);  \\ output: 1
}
```

Comment: `cout << endl << ((A >= B) && (A==C));` Don't fall into the trap of operator precedence.

Comment: It's a matter of [*operator preecedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The expression `cout << endl << (A >= B) && (A==C)` is equivalent to `(cout << endl << (A >= B)) && (A==C)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That could/should be an answer. Especially due to any confusion that the significant overload of the `<<` operator for streams can cause. (Unless there's a good duplicate, of course.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logical operators don't output correct results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860748/logical-operators-dont-output-correct-results)